# Which tools is easy and good to design app for android and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, android

I would like to design a app for android and iPhone. App will consist of min 10 text pages and search function at the top. which tool is better for designing such a app.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to create an app that will work on both platforms, the only real choice is to create an HTML5 Web Application (skinned for mobile devices) that can work offline.

If you need some guidance, I would check out:

[Mobile HTML5 - Tutorial: Your First Mobile HTML5 App](http://www.mobilehtml5.com/post/371921120/tutorial-your-first-mobile-html5-app-the-basics)

The second part of the tutorial discusses how to make your app available offline.

Answer (score 0):

[Titanium Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) seems to be a good way to do that